# Raw in attributes

Tags: sequelize.js

Does Sequelize.js support raw in attributes/columns?

```
models.OrgTraffic.findAll({
"attributes": ["org_name", "account_id", "account_name", {"raw": "sum(requests)"}], ...})
```

It seem to work for order by and group by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I realized that you can use the literal function. In my case, this one works:

```
models.OrgTraffic.findAll({
"attributes": ["org_name", "account_id", "account_name", [sequelize.literal('sum(message_count)'), 'mc'], ...})
```

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to use as much detailed attributes declaration as possible.

You can achieve the same effect by using :

```
models.OrgTraffic.findAll({
    "attributes": [
        "org_name", 
        "account_id", 
        "account_name", 
        [ sequelize.fn("sum", "requests"), "mc" ]
        ...
    ]
})
```

Now sequelize will understand that you are calling a function and will give you back appropriate error messages if something goes wrong with that.